# Ruby DataMapper - Serial column generating null error?

Tags: sql, ruby, sqlite, sinatra, datamapper

In the process of moving some pieces of my configuration into the database on a test app I built, I ran into a very odd issue.  An error is generated whenever I attempt to create a new record in a table.  The error is indicating that the SQL query failed due to the ID column (DataMapper Serial in the model) being null.  The schema for this table and the code being used to create the new row have not been modified in the changes I have made.

```
sinatra.error   
#<DataObjects::IntegrityError: transactions.id may not be NULL (code: 19, sql state: , query: INSERT INTO "transactions" ("uuid", "oid", "store", "txndatetime", "chargetotal") VALUES ('...', '', '...', '...', '...')
```

The ruby statement to create the row:

```ruby
txn = Transaction.create(:uuid => @uuid, :txndatetime => @timestr, :store => store, :chargetotal => params[:subtotal], :oid => params[:oid])
```

The model for the table:

```ruby
class Transaction
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,             Serial
  property :uuid,           String,   :key => true
  property :oid,            String
  property :store,          String
  property :txndatetime,    String
  property :status,         String
  property :refnumber,      String
  property :chargetotal,    String
  property :response_hash,  String,   :length => 255
  property :approval_code,  String
  property :tdate,          String

  validates_presence_of :uuid, :store
  validates_uniqueness_of :uuid
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out.  DataMapper auto_upgrade! borked the schema in the sqlite db.  Dropped the table and regenerating it resolve the issue.

Schema previously looked like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (`id` integer NOT NULL, `uuid` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `oid` varchar(50), `store` varchar(50), `txndatetime` varchar(50), `status` varchar(50), `refnumber` varchar(50), `chargetotal` varchar(50), `response_hash` varchar(255), `approval_code` varchar(50), `tdate` varchar(50), `cc_num` varchar(50), `cc_expm` varchar(50), `cc_expy` varchar(50), PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `uuid`));
```

Now it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "transactions" ("id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "uuid" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, "oid" VARCHAR(50), "store" VARCHAR(50), "txndatetime" VARCHAR(50), "status" VARCHAR(50), "refnumber" VARCHAR(50), "chargetotal" VARCHAR(50), "response_hash" VARCHAR(255), "approval_code" VARCHAR(50), "tdate" VARCHAR(50), "cc_num" VARCHAR(50), "cc_expm" VARCHAR(50), "cc_expy" VARCHAR(50));
```

The missing AUTOINCREMENT seemed to be the culprit here.

Comment: Happened to me. Not sure why.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering your own question though. really helped :)